Fine-tune vs training from scratch
I'm training a 2 class Yolov8 Small detection model, and iterated through the model re-training over the previous best model a few times. Now, I added more data and the size of dataset is 2x (200,000 images now). Generally, should I again fine-tune the previous model or better to train from scratch?
From scratch:
yolo detect train model =yolov8s.pt ...

Finetune:
yolo detect train pretrained =best.pt ...


In my opinion, it would be better to initialize the model weights as per the best model weights obtained previously and then train all the model weight parameters i.e. do not use fine-tuning methods such as LoRA. (So I think this approach is neither fine-tuning nor training from scratch as we have initialized the model weights based on prior information)

Yeah experts have different opinions. Some say given the dataset has changed drastically, it's generally better to train from scratch.
